# Keeping your containers' widths and heights with jLayout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jLayout to layout my code, and I notice that it keeps over-writing my width,height for the components that I am trying to layout.

Currently, I am trying to do a borderLayout on a component that is supposed to have a width of 900 pixels, and a height of 300 pixels. However, when I view it in my browser, not only does it look wrong, but it also strikes out those very properties!

[Here is the mess that is what I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGZXZ.png), as well as the code itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Research Application</title>
        <!-- The necessary imports that give your application the layout and ease-of-implementation that Java has -->
        <!-- First, the jQuery library itself-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Then, all of the jLayout stuff -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jlayout/lib/jquery.sizes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jlayout/lib/jlayout.grid.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jlayout/lib/jlayout.flexlayout.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jlayout/lib/jlayout.flow.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jlayout/lib/jlayout.border.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jlayout/lib/jquery.jlayout.js"></script>
        <!-- including the styleSheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="title">Research Application</h1>
        <!-- This is where you might want to setup the jLayout script -->
        <script>
            // don't you just love function pointers?
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // in here goes all of the stuff to layout
                // first, make the borderLayout for the applicationWindow itself
                $('#applicationWindow').layout({
                    type: 'border',
                    maximumWidth: 900,
                    height: 300,
                    hgap: 3,
                    vgap: 3
                });
                // then, layout the questionPanel into verticalLayout
                // next, make the picturesContainer into a horizontalLayout
            });
        </script>
        <!-- need div element that will the container for the application itself -->
        <div id="applicationWindow">
            <!-- need element that will notify the user of the question number, as well as a way to change the number programmatically -->
            <label id="problemNumberLabel" class="north">
            Question number: 0 of 10 <!-- This is subject to change -->
            </label>
            <!-- need left arrow widget (You might want to do what Facebook did for the pictures, with the CSS and everything, and use <a> -->
            <button class="navigatorButton west" id="leftArrowButton">
                <<
            </button>
            <!-- need div element that will house the inner panel -->
            <div id="questionPanel" class="center">
                <!-- Content to be determined possibly by either JavaScript (via the html() function, or the innerHTML attribute), or by controlling the file
                     that gets loaded to here -->


      </div>
            <!-- need right arrow widget (You might want to do what Facebook did for the pictures, with the CSS and everything, and use <a> -->
            <button class="navigatorButton east" id="rightArrowButton">
                >>
            </button>
            <!-- container for lower buttons -->
            <div id="lowerButtonsContainer" class="south">
                <!-- This is where you put the "Share","Log on" buttons -->
                <button id="ShareButton"></button>
                <button name="LogOnButton"></button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my style code as well:

```
#title
{
    text-align: center;
}

#problemNumberLabel
{
    text-align: right;
}

#applicationWindow,#problemNumberLabel
{
    width: 900px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#applicationWindow
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 300px;
}

.navigatorButton
{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;  // make the color of the buttons white
}
```

I am using jLayout, which you can get access to from here: http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jlayout/ . **Is there a way to keep the width, and height to what they are in the stylesheet? (I am trying to keep the Java-style layouts.**

Comment: When I tried to force the width of applicationWindow to be 900 pixels (with `$('#applicationWindow').css({"width", "900"});` right after where I set up the borderLayout), it not only breaks the borderLayout, but positions my elements vertically! For some reason, the elements even protrude out of the div element!!

What the heck is going on, and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; /* it was as simple as putting `resize: false` in the layout(). The right button did not set up right, but that was fixed with this line of code: 
`$('#rightArrowButton').css({left: 900 - ($('#rightArrowButton').outerWidth())});`
*/